# Free path distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm studying statistical mechanics, and I'm trying to resolve some problem known from my thermodynamics course. So I want to *calculate mean free path* for particles with a concentration $n$ and scattering cross section $\sigma$ using **only statistical approach**. I understand that for the first step I need to find the probability distribution of the free path of the molecules of gas between successive collisions and then calculate the average value. But here I have some troubles, because I have never solved something like this.

I would be grateful if someone would give me some links or give some ideas.

Comment: From what textbook are you studying? Are you trying to arrive at results such as $\lambda=(n\sigma)^{-1}$ or $\lambda=(\sqrt{2}n\sigma)^{-1}$? You can look in K. Huang - Statistical Mechanics, Chapter 5.1.

Comment: Generally, if you have two physical quantities $a,b$ of some dimensions, the products $a^nb^m$ are standard candidates for characteristical dimensions. In your case for concentration $\sim m^{-3}$ and cross section $\sim m^2$, you find $c^n \sigma^m$ to have dimension $\text{length}^{-3m+2n}$. If $-3m+2n=1$, that product is of dimension length. The mean free path will be that times some geometric factor. This doesn't solve you problem of course, but it's a helpful way for analysis of physical systems.

Comment: @NijankowskiV. Thank you for your response! I don't understand one moment in your link. Why K. Huang use the most probable speed of a molecula in formulae $\lambda=\frac{n}{2Z} \bar{v}$ (5.2)instead of the average speed?